# Extend to 2 external monitors using Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650, driver 535 (proprietary and tested) and only one of my two external monitors is recognized.

I was previously running 20.04 with two old monitors and it was plug and play basically. I replaced my old monitors with 2 new ones and upgraded the Linux version, but I cannot get the second monitor to work.

I have tried different drivers, reverted to 20.04, reinstalled 22.04, and none of that has worked for me so far. I did not try all the available drivers, so if there’s one that’s better suited for my GPU I would appreciate learning about it. Or anything else i can try? Thanks!

Comment: For the monitor that isn't recognized, is it recognized if it is the only monitor or if it is plugged into the same port that the recognized monitor is plugged into? Also and for each monitor, are you using hdmi or something else? Also also, how is it not recognized, i.e., does it not show up in the system settings under display? Have you tried any commands like `xrandr --listmonitors` to list the monitors (it should be noted that I think you will have to be using X11 instead of Wayland when you log in to use the xrandr command)?